# How to show the start date for an INSTANCE of a recurring Series?

Tags: vba, outlook

Using VBA, I need to show the start date of each INSTANCE of a recurring appointment in Outlook.

The problem is that when I use appt.start it shows the start date of the SERIES, which is not helpful!!

Example: a recurring appointment happens on the first of every month in 2009.
I want to show 12 INSTANCES, with 12 DIFFERENT start dates (1/1/09, 2/1/09, etc).
In other words, all 12 should NOT show start date = 1/1/09.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A date restriction will pick up instances of a recurring appointment that occur between the dates specified BUT when you interrogate the properties of the instance - for example `.IsRecurring` or `.AllDayEvent`, Outlook redirects the pointer towards the first recurring appointment (the parent as it were).  The way round this is to examine the start and end date (copy to local variables) before you lose them by examining other properties.

```
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olRec As Outlook.Recipient

Dim myCalItems As Outlook.Items
Dim strRestriction As String

Dim ItemstoCheck As Outlook.Items
Dim MyItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Dim datAppStart As Date
Dim datAppEnd As Date

Set myCalItems = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRec, olFolderCalendar).Items

' Including recurrent appointments requires sorting by the Start property, apparently!
myCalItems.Sort "[Start]", False
myCalItems.IncludeRecurrences = True

strRestriction = "[Start]<= " & Quote(datEndDate & " 12:00 AM") & " AND [End] >= " & _
    Quote(datStartDate & " 11:59 PM")
Set ItemstoCheck = myCalItems.Restrict(strRestriction)

For Each MyItem In ItemstoCheck
    If MyItem.Class = olAppointment Then        

'Save Start and end dates in case replaced by first instance of recurring appointment
datAppStart = MyItem.Start
datAppEnd = MyItem.End
```

etc.

Comment: This was the crux for me:
`' Including recurrent appointments requires sorting by the Start property, apparently!
myCalItems.Sort "[Start]", False
myCalItems.IncludeRecurrences = True`